# Docker - list images by tag

Tags: docker

Docker docs give:

```
docker image ls [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

but this assumes you'll specify a repo.

How do you list local images **just** by tag?

Comment: You may use this `docker images | grep "yourTAGhere"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just with the docker CLI on it's own. The CLI only supports listing all images (including or excluding intermediate layers), images matching a repo, or images matching a repo:tag.

In a shell then you can pipe to grep as has been mentioned in comments, otherwise you will have to parse the output of whichever method you use to list images.

Comment: Guess I was just being lazy. Was hoping for a command line option instead of having to `grep`.

Answer (score 5):

Nice question! I was playing with `docker image ls` and have found that you do not have to specify repository. The following actually work:

```
# displays images with tag: latest
docker image ls *:latest

# displays all images but not those with: <none>
docker image ls *:*
```

**edit:**

`docker image ls *:latest` has some inconsistencies. I noticed that some images are not displayed whereas `docker image ls | grep latest` shows them. I'll get back if I find out why...

**Update** by [Santhosh V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4902994/santhosh-v):
It looks like a special character needs to be specified in the filter like `docker image ls *\*:*` for considering a \ in the image name

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#docker images | grep [tag]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use the Docker API, see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags

see also

https://gist.github.com/kizbitz/175be06d0fbbb39bc9bfa6c0cb0d4721

If the Docker API is on

`http://myregistry.com`

on the port 2375, then you will do something like

`curl http://myregistry.com:2375/images/json`

you will find in /images/json the same info as

`docker images`

will show

Answer (score 0):

The following works on `Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289`

`docker images --filter=reference='*:sometag'`

The [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/) can help you with more such filters.